# Why i can't append some html in to the desired element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i hope someone can lend me a hand, i have been trying to insert some code via .post using jquery everything seem to works fine but the response data doesn't insert on the conhere div

html

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a main">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1##2##2##1080|2" name="pro1" id="pro1" class="checkpro">
            <label for="pro1"> product description
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b side">
        <div class="conhere">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).on( "change",".checkpro", function(event, ui) {
    var checkedpro = $(this).is(':checked')?1:0;
    if (checkedpro==1){
        var variable=$(this).val().split("##");
        $.post("product.php", h{row :contenedor[0],
                                mul : variable[1],
                                can : variable[2],
                            pri: variable[3],
                                id : variable[4]},
            function(data){
                $(this).parents(".ui-grid-a").find(".conhere").empty().append(data).trigger('create');
        });
else{
    $(this).parents(".ui-grid-a").find(".conhere").empty();
}
```

Comment: `.parents(".ui-block-a")` should be `.parents(".ui-grid-a")`

Comment: sorry it was $( "#notaayuda" ) since i'm using jquery mobile but to make it more clean i changed to document, forgot to erase the ""

Comment: @Omar: Yeah, I'd removed that. I forgot that jQuery makes `change` bubble reliably.

Comment: Side note: You dont need to `.trigger("create")` unless you're appending a jQM widget.

Comment: using jquery mobile i need the .trigger("create") to render the page correctly

Comment: What kind of elements are you adding dynamically?

Comment: @Atondo: Please **do not** markedly change the code in the question once you've had answers related to the old code. Add a note saying "I tried X but it didn't work."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues, both with this code:

```
$(this).parents(".ui-block-a").find(".conhere")...
```

The first issue is that the `.conhere` element doesn't exist within `.ui-block-a`. It exists in `.ui-block-b`. (And both `.ui-block-a` and `.ui-block-b` are within `.ui-grid-a`.) `find` only looks at descendant elements of the elements in the set where it's called.

The second issue is that `this` is no longer what it was outside the call to `$.post`. So we want to capture it in a variable we close over.

Finally, in this case I would use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), not [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
$(this).closest(".ui-grid-a").find(".ui-block-b .conhere")...
// or
$(this).closest(".ui-grid-a").find(".conhere")...
```

Combining the above:

```
$(document).on("change", ".checkpro", function (event, ui) {
    var $elm = $(this),                           // <== Remember $(this)
        checkedpro = $elm.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    if (checkedpro == 1) {
        var variable = $elm.val().split("##");
        $.post("product.php", h {
                row: contenedor[0],
                mul: variable[1],
                can: variable[2],
                pri: variable[3],
                id: variable[4]
            },
            function (data) {
                // v-------------------------------- use it, and note 'closest'
                $elm.closest(".ui-grid-a").find(".conhere").empty().append(data).trigger('create');
            });
    } // <== This } was also missing
    else {
        $elm.closest(".ui-grid-a").find(".conhere").empty();
    }
```

Comment: i'm using ".ui-grid-a" and still nothing

Comment: the product.php loads but is not inserted on the .conhere

Comment: @Atondo: There was also a `this` issue, *and* a fundamental syntax error. Updated.

Comment: sorry man, it's my first time posting a question and my actual code is a bit more tricky i tried to simplify it but i got bad copy paste skills

Comment: thanks man it's working now i used  var $elm = $(this);
instead of the ","